# React Native Navigation replacement

Tags: react-native

I have generated all the pages of my desired application separately with custom components and in the order I want. now to navigate between them, if I want to use the Native Stack Navigator, by default it changes my Header and Drawer and Back button, etc. Then I need to replace them all one by one back to my own design, which is not nice.

Is there any better solution to navigate between pages without replacing my custom design of pages?

i.e By pressing the button on the home page, I simply want to replace the home page with the next page, which I have already designed the full structure including back button in header and title and drawer etc. I don't want it to be automatically replaced with another design depending on the platform, in short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to disable header of a component in navigation Stack

use

```
 options={{ headerShown: false }
```